# createObjectURL blob url not secure in Firefox

Tags: javascript, security, firefox, indexeddb

I'm trying to save downloaded file from secure url (https) with browser but I'm having problems with Firefox.

I use indexedDB to store file in browser memory and when download is finished, I try to save the file in my computer (I'm using a Mac but I think it's not important)

I have this piece of code:

```
var fileRequest = fileHandle.getFile(); //from indexedDB
fileRequest.onsuccess = function(event){

{...}
var file = event.target.result;
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file, {type : fileMimeType, autoRevoke : true});

//I did this with form and not with a href because:
//https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=979227

var form = document.createElement('form');
                        form.action = url;
                        document.body.appendChild(form);
                        form.submit();
```

The browser asks to save this file in Downloads folder and everything seems to work fine BUT it prompts always this message:

"The information entered on this page will be sent through a not secure connection and could be read by third parties. Are you sure you want to send this information?"

If you click 'OK' the file is saved fine, but this security warning is the worst think a user wants to read in a webpage, so the user scares and runaway.

The created url by createObjectURL is a secure url too because is like:
blob:https//blahblah

This warning doesn't appear in Chrome (using his own filesystem method).

Please I need help :(

Comment: Any update for chrome on the same ?

Comment: I have faced the same problem,@AliMola did you got any solution for this, can you please let me know

Comment: No, sorry, no updates here. There's an old abandoned project now :/

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for avoid security warning in Firefox

```
 var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(some_blob);

 var fr = document.createElement('iframe');
 fr.frameBorder = 0;
 fr.width = 1;
 fr.height = 1;
 document.body.appendChild(fr);

 var doc = fr.contentDocument;
 var form = doc.createElement('form');
 form.action = blobURL;
 doc.body.appendChild(form);
 form.submit();
 setTimeout(function(){
    fr.parentNode.removeChild(fr);
 }, 100);
```